# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource problem

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given” error while trying to create a php shopping cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481963/warning-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

I don't get it, I see no mistakes in this code but there is this error, please help:
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource problem

```
<?php

      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","nitoryolai123$%^");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("school", $con);
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
    ?>     


                           <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>             
                                     <table class="a"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#D3D3D3">
    <tr>

    <form name="formcheck" method="get" action="updateact.php" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
    <td>
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
    <tr>

    <td  colspan="16" height="25"  style="background:#5C915C; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: left"><strong><font size="2">Update Students</td>


    <tr>
    <td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">*I D Number:</td>
    <td width="30"><input  name="idnum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">*Year:</td>
    <td width="30"><input  name="yr" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $row["YEAR"]; ?>"></td>

<?php } ?>
```

I'm just trying to load the data in the forms but I don't know why that error appears. What could possibly be the mistake in here?

Comment: I would recommend to at least cast `$_GET['id']` to `int`:
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=" . (int)$_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not doing **error checking** after the call to [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In case `mysql_query` fails, it returns `false`, a `boolean` value. When you pass this to `mysql_fetch_array` function (which expects a `mysql result object`) we get this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
```

always do it this way and it will tell you what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
$indo=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$indo'");
```

I think this works..

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is an error in `mysql_query()`. Have you checked to make sure it worked? Output the value of `$result` and `mysql_error()`. You may have misspelled something, selected the wrong database, have a permissions issue, etc. So:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id']; // this also sanitizes it
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
  die("Error running $sql: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Sanitizing `$_GET['id']` is *really* important. You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` but casting it to an `int` is sufficient for integers. Basically you want to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your query ran successfully and you got the results. You can check like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']) or die(mysql_error());


if (is_resource($result))
{
   // your while loop and fetch array function here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database what is the type of "IDNO"? You may need to escape the sql here:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this :

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

To get the error you're getting, it means that `$result` is not a resource.

In your code, `$result` is obtained this way :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
```

**If the SQL query fails, `$result` will not be a resource**, but a boolean -- see [**`mysql_query`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_query).

I suppose there's **an error in your SQL query** -- so it fails, `mysql_query` returns a boolean, and not a resource, and `mysql_fetch_array` cannot work on that.

You should check if the SQL query returns a result or not :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
if ($result !== false) {
    // use $result
} else {
    // an error has occured
    echo mysql_error();
    die;    // note : echoing the error message and dying 
            // is OK while developping, but not in production !
}
```

With that, you should get a message that indicates the error that occured while executing your query -- this should help figure out what the problem is ;-)

Also, you should escape the data you're putting in your SQL query, to avoid [**SQL injections**][2] !

For example, here, you should make sure that `$_GET['id']` contains nothing else than an integer, using something like this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=" . intval($_GET['id']));
```

Or you should check this before trying to execute the query, to display a nicer error message to the user.