# Basic PHP/MySQL Error with mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

The error I get:

```
...mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...
```

`awayid` is in the address bar properly. I can print it out just fine, but for some reason the following code gives me the above error.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from team where id=" . $_GET['awayid']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

**EDIT** Tried the mysql_error(). It seems I forgot to select a database... however, even why I use `mysql_select_db('gamelydb');` I still get the mysql error `No database selected`

Comment: That error means that you query failed. You can use [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to find out why. The `mysql_query` function returns `false` (a boolean) when it fails.

Comment: This error means "$result" did not contain a valid result set. Their must be some error in your query which most probably is that $_GET['awayid'] is empty. Try debugging the query by echoing it and then running directly in MySQL or using mysql_error() function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697438/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-problem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is failing... Therefore `$result` is set to `false`.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from team where id=" . $_GET['awayid']);
var_dump($result); // bool(false)
```

Call [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/mysql_error) to get the error message for your query:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is failing and returning a boolean FALSE. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select ...") or die(mysql_error());
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- add this
```

This will kill the script and show you the exact reason the query is failing.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query() returns false if the query is unsuccessful, i.e. an error occured. That is why you need to check $result for being *false* first.

Use mysql_error() to output the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure there is results from your query :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// echo $row[] ... ;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your query is very open to SQL injection attacks.  Do not directly insert anything from $_GET or $_POST (or really anywhere) into your query.  At the minimum, use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the variable.

`mysql_query` is returning false becuase there is something wrong with the query.  You can use `mysql_error` to see what the last reported error is.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result = mysql_query("select * from team where id='" . $_GET['awayid']) . "'") {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Anyway...you know that writing a `$_GET` parameter right into the SQL query is very very bad? Try it with [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try and search around first Tory, we answer these questions over and over again, next time please search around.

The reason why this error occurs is because your running a query with `mysql_query` that fails, because it fails it returns false, you then pass the value of `false` to `mysql_fetch_array`, it's like doing `mysql_fetch_array(false)`

You need to make sure that `mysql_query` is successful:

try something like this:

```
if(false !== ($result = mysql_query("select * from team where id=" . $_GET['awayid'])))
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}else
{
    die("Query has failed: " . mysql_error())
}
```