# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697438/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-problem)

This is part of a dynamic menu on the website, where I'm taking the name of the collections from the database.
This is my database structure

```
id INT (11)
name VARCHAR (255)
```

And this is my script

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM collections");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<li><a href="photohandler.php?c='.$row['id'].'" class="parent"><span>'.$row['name'].'</span></a>';
}
?>
```

I receive the error:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in index.php on line 107

Comment: You need a call to `mysql_connect()` first. Does connect.php contain such call?

Comment: @user1237671: check the "Related" items to the right on this page.  You will see several duplicate questions already answered.

Comment: Google the error message, 3.6 MILLION results.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Your query has failed somehow, and returned a boolean FALSE instead of a statement handle.

Like below:

```
<?php
            include("connect.php");
             $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM collections");
             if ($query === FALSE) {
                 die(mysql_error());
              }

              if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
              {
             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                 echo
            '<li><a href="photohandler.php?c='.$row['id'].'" class="parent"><span>'.$row['name'].'</span></a>';
              }
           }
?>
```

Comment: There are *no rows*. `mysql_query` is returning `false` ("boolean given").

Comment: You should accept this answer if it's ok.

Comment: Sorry.. didnt have time to go online till now...
Thanks for your help! 
now it says no database selected