# mysql query results in a Warning

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697438/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-problem)

I am a beggiinner when it cames to programming with php. At the moment I am working at a project with a database. A problem appears when I try to call my query: `$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);` I get this error:
[image]

This is my class where I connect to my database:

```
class conectDB{
var $dbUser;
var $dbPassword;
var $dbHost;
var $dbName;

function __construct() {
    $this->dbUser ='root';
    $this->dbPassword = '';
    $this->dbHost = 'localhost';
    $this->dbName = 'db';
    $dbc = mysqli_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName) or die('Fatal error!');
 }
}
```

And here I call my query:

```
$db = new conectDB();
$q='SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category';
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
while(list($id, $category) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)){
 echo '<li><a href="category.php?id='.$id.'" title="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: which debbugger are you using

Comment: It says on php.net : mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) so first parameter is  suppose to be link not object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the instance of `conectDB` class instead of the link returned by `mysqli_connect`.

You may do something like that (note the return you are missing) :

```
class conectDB {
    protected $dbUser;
    protected $dbPassword;
    protected $dbHost;
    protected $dbName;
    protected $link;

    function __construct() {
        $this->dbUser ='root';
        $this->dbPassword = '';
        $this->dbHost = 'localhost';
        $this->dbName = 'db';

        $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName) or die('Fatal error!');
     }

    public function getLink() {
      return $this->link;
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
$db = new conectDB();
$q='SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category';
$r = mysqli_query($db->getLink(), $q);
```

On a side node, you should not use the `var` keyword anymore : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php